# How to find out which disk is "sd 0:4:0:0"

Tags: devices

I run Ubuntu on a 32GB USB jump drive. Started recently, I kept getting "sd 0:4:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device". How do I find out if this is the internal hard drive or the external USB drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a bit of googling because I was also curious what the 4 digits with colons meant in terms of drive identification. I believe the 4 digits are the [SCSI numbers](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-2.4-HOWTO/scsiaddr.html).

**Update**

If you just install and run `lsscsi` it will give you something like this:

```
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      LITEON LCH-256V2 902   /dev/sda 
[3:0:0:0]    disk    Kingston DataTraveler G3  PMAP  /dev/sdb
```

**Original Post**

If you run `ls -ld /sys/block/sd*/device` it should look like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb 21 18:11 /sys/block/sda/device -> ../../../0:0:0:0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb 21 18:12 /sys/block/sdb/device -> ../../../3:0:0:0
```

which means 0:0:0:0 is sda and 3:0:0:0 is sdb.

You can sort out what sda and sdb are by using `sudo lshw -class disk -short` or something similar.

In my case:

```
H/W path               Device     Class          Description
============================================================
/0/100/14/0/1/0.0.0    /dev/sdb   disk           16GB SCSI Disk
/0/0/0.0.0             /dev/sda   disk           256GB LITEON LCH-256V2
```

sda is my internal drive and sdb is my flash drive.